# Jboss RedHat Fuse and Spring Boot Integration

Tags: spring-boot, jbossfuse

Well, i know there is 3 types of fuse: standalone (karaf, eap and springboot), openshift and cloud.

Thinking about standalone type i have this 3 sub-types: Apache Karaf, EAP and SpringBoot.

[image]

- **Apache karaf**: I downloaded it from RedHat website, in this link: https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/. And i can use only **blueprint xml**
- **EAP**: I can't download it because it's a commercial license, so i can't test.
- **Spring Boot**: Where can i download it ? Can i use Fluent Java API in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 3 types of Red Hat Fuse distribution (there is no specific distribution for Spring Boot applications):

1. **Red Hat Fuse on OpenShift** : Fuse on OpenShift consists of an application and all required runtime components packaged inside a **Docker image**, you can see documentation for how to [Develop an Application for the Spring Boot Image](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.3/html-single/fuse_on_openshift_guide/index#spring-boot-image).
2. **Red Hat Fuse standalone** : application runs inside a runtime which options are Apache Karaf or Red Hat EAP (appeared on the picture above the question)
3. **Red Hat Fuse Online**

According to [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.3/html-single/deploying_into_spring_boot/index#about-standalone-springboot) from Red Hat site :

> In standalone deployment mode, a Spring Boot application is packaged
>   as a Jar file and runs directly inside the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).
>   That is, the Spring Boot application can be run directly using the
>   java command with the -jar option.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. The picture in RedHat site don't make it clear.